# How to tell if Apple Hide My Email is being used?

Tags: mail.app, email, apple-id

I use Apple Hide My Email for `My Email`.  When I look at an email sent using the feature, the `From` field reads my Apple ID and not the `Hide My email address` that I used.

How can I tell if the email was sent using Hide **My Email** vs. **my Apple ID** that is showing?

I do not see the hide my email address anywhere in the headers or raw source.

Comment: How are you sending this message?  From what App on what device?

Comment: Update from below. “ When I receive an email from one of my hide my email addresses that I created and sent out, when I hit “ reply “, I see in the to field the hide my email address , but when I view the sent email, I see my Apple ID email address in the from field - not the hide my email address“.  Using apple mail on iPad, MBP and iPhone using apple mail app. Sorry for delay in replying - did not get email notification of reply….

Answer (score 1):

When using Hide my Email from Apple Mail, it doesn't automatically use the feature by default. You must choose it with each email. See this image from Apple:

[image]

So you need to tap on your return address, and select Hide My Email for each message you wish to send.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-hide-my-email-iphf277f837e/ios

Comment: I know the above - what you show.  When I receive an email from one of my hide my email addresses that I created and sent out, when I hit “ reply “, I see in the to field the hide my email address , but when I view the sent email, I see my Apple ID email address in the from field - not the hide my email address.

Comment: @Stumped Are you receiving the email on your own device? It may recognize the fake address and replace it with your Apple ID. Try viewing the raw source of the message.

Comment: Yes, my device. When I look at an email sent using the feature, the From field reads my Apple ID and not the Hide My email address that I used.

I do not see the hide my email address anywhere in the headers or raw source.